# Sandcastle Help File Builder - how to change msbuild path?

Tags: .net, msbuild, sandcastle

I'm trying out Sandcastle Help File Builder.  If I run the build from the gui I'm getting this error:

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found

This is because it's in C:\Program Files (x86) directory.

So how do I configure to use that dir instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's only x86 version, so there will be problem with "telling" that you have an x64 operating system, the easiest way is to create and copy missing files to proper directory. In your case copy the missing files from C:\Program Files (x86)  to C:\Program Files\ Should help a little bit.